# How to understand center given by minAreaRect opencv

Tags: opencv, center

I just made a code to detect Contours in a picture, I used minAreaRect for each contour to create Bounding rotated boxes for contours following Opencv Tuition. Finally I can extract each contour's Angel,Width,Height and Center. The result is as below:

Angle given by minAreaRect: -45.00
Width given by minAreaRect:  54.00
Height given by minAreaRect: 50.00
Center given by minAreaRect: 279223213129465860.00

I don't really understnad what they means, what unit are they using except the Angle. I expect the center should be something like (x,y). Would anyone can help? Many thnks.

Comment: `279223213129465860.00` that value has a heavy garbage smell... Besides that, that function returns a "Rotated Rectangle", have a look here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#details

Comment: Please double check that you're not mixing debug libs in release, or viceversa